# Missing information and change format viewing itext pdf autofilled

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I got a problem with my generated Pdf files (as a template I created a pdf using Adobe Acrobat Pro with acroforms), I can view them correctly on Chrome, IE and Mozilla Firefox, also using my android mobile, but I have some problems with windows reader app and iOS divices...

This is my generated pdf: http://i58.tinypic.com/30ihmxf.jpg

But when I open the same pdf on windows reader app, at first sight everything is ok then if I click an element of my form I get this (My text size and format changes): http://i60.tinypic.com/dwdphc.jpg

And finally if I open the pdf on an ipod the field's information is missing: 
//i57.tinypic.com/f3yosx.jpg (please ad the "http:" I can only post 2 links)

This is my Code

```
    PdfReader reader;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    AcroFields form = null;
    String categorias="";
    DateFormat dateFormat=null;
    Calendar cal = null;

    try {
        reader = new PdfReader("gacetas\\templates\\template.pdf");
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("temps\\header_"+noGaceta+".pdf"));
        stamper.getAcroFields().setGenerateAppearances(true);
        //BaseFont bf =  BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf",  BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        form = stamper.getAcroFields();

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        form.setField("fecha", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        for(int i=0;i<combinacionesCategorias.size();i++){
            categorias= categorias.concat(i+1+") "+combinacionesCategorias.get(i).toString()).concat(" \n");

        }

        form.setField("categorias", categorias);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(GeneradorGacetas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(GeneradorGacetas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I thought that maybe "setFieldProperty" or "setGenerateAppearances" could solve the problem, but it didn't

```
form.setGenerateAppearances(true);
form.setFieldProperty("fecha", "textfont", bf, null);
form.setFieldProperty("fecha", "textsize", new Float(30), null);
form.setFieldProperty("fecha", "setfflags",PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
form.setField("fecha", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

I really hope you can help me and thank you in advance

Comment: When you click the form field, does only the styling (font type, font size, color, ...) change? In your screen shots the text itself is also different. When you click the field and then click outside the field, without making any changes to its value, do you get the original appearance again? It would be useful to provide the PDF file.

Comment: Certain readers do not support form fields at all. So if you want to ensure that your PDF look the same in most readers you have to fill it out and afterwards flatten it with iText. You can't edit/change the form fields afterwards (because the fields are gone) however it will look the same...